# How to create a TFRecord in PHP?

Tags: php, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I would like to create a TFRecord file in PHP, but I'm not sure where to start, so a bit of help would be welcome (I also figure this question could help a few out here).

Here's what the code looks like in Python:

```
writer = tensorflow.python_io.TFRecordWriter("training.tfrecords")
for example in examples: 
    example = tensorflow.train.Example(
        features=tensorflow.train.Features(
            feature={
                'label': tensorflow.train.Feature(
                    float_list=tensorflow.train.FloatList(value=[
                        float(example['label'])
                    ])),
                'features': tensorflow.train.Feature(
                    float_list=tensorflow.train.FloatList(value=[
                        float(example['first_feature']),
                        float(example['second_feature'])
                    ])),
            }
        )
    )
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Here are the references I've been using (unsuccessfully) so far:

- [PHP Protobuf packages](https://packagist.org/search/?q=protobuf)
- [how to create a TFRecord file in Java/Scala](http://jakzaprogramowac.pl/pytanie/16111,pure-java-scala-code-for-writing-tensorflow-tfrecords-data-file)
- [TFRecord python source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py)
- [TFRecord format details](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/python_io#tfrecords_format_details)
- [example.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto)

I'm not too familiar with Protobuf, I would appreciate a few pointers. Some of the things that confuse me at the moment:

- in the Java/Scala article, they mention a CRC mask, and I'm not too sure what that is and how to implement it in PHP
- do I need to use TensorFlow's `example.proto`?
- do I need to create a TFRecord class? a TFRecordWriter class?

Thank you for your help.